# Testing Silverlight WP7 Apps with Pex - Assembly version to Silverlight 5 dll not found

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, pex

as the release notes of Pex show, it is possible to test Windows Phone Apps.
Now I created a very basic Windows Phone app and wanted to test a simple method in it with Pex (Run Pex). I'm using Visual Studio 10 Ultimate and Silverlight 5.
After I've pressed Run Pex, no test cases are created. But some errors are appearing.
It says that file:///c:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.10411.0\System.Windows.dll or a dependency to that is not found. But the file exists. Anyone has an idea how I can help myself?